# mySQL stored procedure to insert row into table always inserts 0 values for all columns

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, insert

I'm attempting to do an insert store procedure on mySQL as a little test.
The end result inserts all zeros into a row rather than the values passed into the definer.

My Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Test` (
IN IDvar int,
IN FirstNamevar nvarchar(50),
IN LastNamevar nvarchar(50),
IN Nationalityvar nvarchar(50),
In Agevar nvarchar(50),
)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO testtable (
ID,
FirstName,
LastName,
Nationality,
Age)

VALUES(
IDvar,
FirstNamevar,
LastNamevar,
Nationalityvar,
Agevar);

END
```

I click apply and get the following code to construct the store procedure

```
USE `testdb`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `Test`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `testdb` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Test` (
IN IDvar int,
IN FirstNamevar nvarchar(50),
IN LastNamevar nvarchar(50),
IN Nationalityvar nvarchar(50),
In Agevar nvarchar(50),
)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO testtable (
ID,
FirstName,
LastName,
Nationality,
Age)

VALUES(
IDvar,
FirstNamevar,
LastNamevar,
Nationalityvar,
Agevar);

END$$

DELIMITER;
```

If I look at the constructed store procedure code I get the following

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@localhost` PROCEDURE `Test`(
IN IDvar int,
IN FirstNamevar nvarchar(50),
IN LastNamevar nvarchar(50),
IN Nationalityvar nvarchar(50),
In Agevar nvarchar(50),
)

BEGIN

INSERT INTO testtable (
ID,
FirstName,
LastName,
Nationality,
Age)

VALUES(
IDvar,
FirstNamevar,
LastNamevar,
Nationalityvar,
Agevar);

END
```

When I then execute this store procedure with values:

```
IDvar = 3
FirstNamevar = TestFirstName
LastNamevar = TestLastName
Nationalityvar = GER
Age = 20
```

I get this out

```
set @IDvar = 0;
set @FirstNamevar = '0';
set @LastNamevar = '0';
set @Nationalityvar = '0';
set @Agevar = '0';
call testdb.Test(@IDvar, @FirstNamevar, @LastNamevar, @Nationalityvar, @Agevar);
select @IDvar, @FirstNamevar, @LastNamevar, @Nationalityvar, @Agevar;
```

Obviously this end with a row with all zero values. Anyone know why this is happening?

Cheers

Comment: noticed a typo In Agevar nvarchar(50),) with the comma at the end. Just a note that this isn't in the code on mySQL was my mistake when typing it in on here

Answer (score 0):

1) You are passing all zeros into the stored procedure. So that is what is then inserted into the table.

2) Your SELECT at the end does not read from the table you insert into in the stored procedure but rather just returns the values of the variables - all of which are 0.

So everything is working as your code is telling it to.

Comment: I realise that, but when I execute the store procedure and pass in these values into the definer e.g.
IDvar = 3,
FirstNamevar = TestFirstName,
LastNamevar = TestLastName,
Nationality = ENG,
Age = 20,

It ends up passing all zeros

Comment: How are you executing the stored procedure? What is your calling code or are you doing it through a GUI?

Comment: Using mySQL Workbench, finding my stored procedure and clicking the lightning bolt next to it.
I then type the values into the Definer and click the execute button

Comment: What happens if you call it manually - i.e.
    CALL Test(3, 'TestFirstName', 'TestLastName', 'ENG', '20');

Comment: That actually works, and row is inserted, doesn't seem to like me doing it through the definer

Comment: So the stored procedure is fine but either there is a bug with the GUI or you are not entering the parameters in the correct place. Do other procedures execute OK when entering parameters via the GUI? In any event calling it via a SQL query is the preferred option anyway as you have more transparency of what is actually being run.

Comment: Other stored procedures do the same thing and use all zeros, either a bug or there's a setting somewhere causing this. Unfortunately these tests are to then run the stored procedures with an OLEDB Call store procedure in another program and that causes the same thing to happen but thank you regardless.